# C# Writing multiple records to one line

Tags: c#

I am using c# to write create a text file. I am attempting to write 2 records on one line in a text file. My data source is from a result set from a stored procedure.

Here is the code that I have. At the moment I am only writing record by record. I would like to write 2 records on one line into a text file.

example:

record 1   record 6

record 2   record 7

record 3   record 8

record 4   record 9

record 5   record 10

record 11   record 16

record 12   record 17

record 13   record 18

record 14   record 19

record 15   record 20

```
    public bool SalesPriceIndexProcess()
    {
        int page = 1, count = 1;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Properties.Settings.Default.Path + SalesPriceDirectoryReportName, FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        foreach (ManhattanLUSESalesPriceIndex_Result s in _db.ManhattanLUSESalesPriceIndex())
        {
            if (count == 1)
            {
                SalesPriceHeaderWrite(s.BldgClassCd, ref fs, ref sw);
            }
            string saleDate = s.SaleDt.ToString();
            sw.WriteLine("{0,13:C0}{1,-5} {2,-4} {3,5} {4,3} {5,15:C0}{6} {7,-8} {8,4}"
                , s.SalePriceAmt, s.MultiSplitCd
                , Convert.ToInt16(s.StoriesNbr) + s.LandUseMajorCd
                , (s.LegalBlkId + "-"), s.LegalLot
                , s.TransAssdTotalAmt, s.BldgClassCd.PadRight(2)
                , (saleDate.Length > 6 ? saleDate.Substring(4, 2) + "/" + saleDate.Substring(6, 2) + "/" + saleDate.Substring(2, 2) : "")
                , page    
                );

            PclIdPageIndexDict.Add(s.PclId, page);
            if (count % 5 == 0)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(SalesPriceLineBreak);
            }
            if (count % 145 == 0)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(SalesPricePageBreak);
            }

            count++; //increment by 1
            page = count % 145;
        }
        return true;
```

Comment: how do i write 2 records from a dataset onto the same line into a text file?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to store the last 5 rows in a queue. Where you write out your line you will need to say something like:

```
while(!eof) {
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    queue.enqueue(readline());
  }

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
   write(queue.dequeue());
   write(readline());
   write('\n');
  }
}
```

Is your question about C# syntax or the logic to do the line pairs?

Comment: both actually. I am fairly new to c# so explanation of syntax is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(_db.ManhattanLUSESalesPriceIndex().Count() < 5)
{
// throw
}
else
{
    var collectionStore = _db.ManhattanLUSESalesPriceIndex().ToList();
    for(int i = 5; i < collectionStore.Count(); i++)
    {
        var recordN = collectionStore[i-5];
        // do whatever outputting you want
        var recordNPlusFive = collectionStore[i];
        // do whatever outputting you want
        }
    }
}
```

Edited code

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it without checking my syntax, got my languages wrong. Updated my post to help you.